# Problem in changing wallpaper through service

Tags: python, windows, service

I have a python program: -

```
import ctypes
import time

while True:
    path = r"path to image.jpg"
    res = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, path, 0)
    time.sleep(3)
```

which continuously changes the current desktop wallpaper to image.jpg. I have it converted to an executable using pyinstaller with --noconsole flag.

Next, I have a service that checks if this executable is not running, then start it...

Now the problem is that the executable starts successfully, reports in the task manager, but the wallpaper does not change, and the value of res is 0.
I doubled checked it and I am pretty sure that the image is in the path specified. Moreover, the executable runs perfectly if it is executed by double clicking...

I know that service cannot execute a program which has some sort of GUI, but that's why I have disabled the console of the executable... 
How to make it work?

Comment: maybe you need admin

Comment: I don't understand, I have all the admin rights, and the executable works fine if run without 'run as administrator'.

Comment: You can run it without admin but it often doesn't take effect when system changes are involved

Answer (score 0):

First you should give your program administrator privileges. And it works.

```
import ctypes
import time
import sys


def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False


if is_admin():
    while True:
        path = "C:/004.jpg"
        res = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, path, 0)
        time.sleep(3)
else:
    if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, __file__, None, 1)
    else:
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, u"runas", unicode(sys.executable), unicode(__file__), None, 1)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this code is compatible when I am calling this executable through a service? Because in that case, I am not getting a prompt asking me to grant user rights, so I am assuming the service starts it (by default) as admin. The process again shows up in the task manager, but wallpaper doesn't change...

Comment: @EReload Yes. You won't be alerted if you don't perform permission checks. Your code does not take effect when pyshell does not have permissions, it works if have

Comment: @EReload Are you sure you're on the right path? try full dir

Comment: @EReload it not works? What is your version of py & win?

Comment: @EReload it works with win10 64 bit & py2 64 bit or py3 64bit

Comment: I have win 10 Python 3.7.4 64-bit

Comment: @EReload check your env, maybe software or something is wrong, you can open a administrator cmd shell or powershell, and enter pyshell or ipython shell, and test your main code `ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW`